# Download is not starting on click event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
var _t = $(this);
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').attr("href",_OBJECT_URL);
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').attr('download', fileName);
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').css('display','block');
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').click();
```

`_OBJECT_URL` contains a link like this `blob:https://www.example.com/53713783-ba94-4d5d-9221-54aa1fd87738 CNN:14032:12 2019-07-22_12h32m44s.jpg`

and `fileName` contains a name line this `2019-07-22_12h32m44s.jpg`

I have multiple ".save-file" link clicks on the same page. I also made this function to debug.

```
$(document).on('click','.save-file', function(event){
    console.log("CLICKED");
    console.log($(this).href);
    console.log($(this).download);
});
```

When, I click on .save-file using jquery, this gets printed

> Clicked
>
> Undefined
>
> Undefined

If I click on .save-file manually, download starts.

Comment: did you try trigger("click") instead of .click();

Comment: also show the html code

Comment: I dont use the pointer directly. I use like this. $(_t).parents('td').find('.save-file').attr("href",_OBJECT_URL);

Answer (score 1):

Use a next one

```
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').click(function() {
    window.location = _OBJECT_URL;
});
```

it will propose to a user download your file from url: _OBJECT_URL

and you will non need a next code:

```
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').attr("href",_OBJECT_URL);
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').attr('download', fileName);
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').css('display','block');
```

In case if you want to set propertes `href`, `download`, etc:

```
_t.parents('td').find('.save-file').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('download'); // or $(this).attr('href')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can not access download and href attribute like you did. you need to use .attr() method to access those attribute.

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-file', function(event) {
  console.log("CLICKED");
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  console.log($(this).attr('download'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `attr()` to access element attributes using jQuery.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.save-file', function(event) {
  console.log("CLICKED");
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  console.log($(this).attr('download'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="save-file" href="123" download="456">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-objects does not have href or download -properties, use [attr-function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to retrieve the values:

```
$(document).on('click','.save-file', function(event){
    console.log("CLICKED");
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
    console.log($(this).attr("download"));
});
```